# Recommendation on a book about sound meets style?

Tags: style, phonology

I find the so-called "phonaesthetics" an interesting topic. How words sound good or not when put together, patterns of meaning in letter clusters etc.

Anyone knows of a good source material to read about it, perhaps even academic yet enjoyable? Thanks.

Comment: Would this perhaps be better on the Linguistics site as it does not seem to be specific to learning English?

Comment: Sure! Didn't know about it. Can the post be redirected there?